# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNavigation.ThemeColors.light')

Tags: react-native

Facing this issue due to react navigation in which createDrawerNavigator is creating a problem.

I tried following:

`import {createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation-drawer';`

which didn't worked, but following code is working with performance issues:

`import {createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation';`

Answer (score 1):

I followed this post [#156](https://github.com/react-navigation/tabs/issues/156) and resolved my issue.
Basically, added experimentalImportSupport: true, in metro.config.js.
Then reset.
react-native start --reset-cache
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-package && npm cache clean --force && npm install
And then everything worked...

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded react-navigation to 4.0.10 version and the problem solved.